# How to add custom buttons to map using Bing Maps 6.3 Ajax Control?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bing-maps

Is there a way to add custom buttons to a Bing Map? Something like a custom dashboard, what I want to do with this is to have some buttons to toggle the info/color/etc. displayed in certain pins/polygons by pressing the buttons displayed on the map.

Is there a way to add custom buttons to the map? Or do I have to add the buttons outside the map? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dedicated method on VEMap class, VEMap.AddControl(), see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412435.aspx

Here is the interesting part in the official example:

```
function AddControl()
{
    var el = document.createElement("div"); 
    el.id = "myControl" + i; 
    el.style.top = 100 + (i * 10); 
    el.style.left = 100 + (i * 10);            
    el.style.border = "2px solid black";
    el.style.background = "White";
    el.innerHTML = el.id;  
    map.AddControl(el);
}
```

Another way you can use is to do it by manipulating the corresponding DOM element of the dashboard.
See Chris' blog post: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2010/12/18/Bing-Maps-Ajax-7-Add-Custom-Navigation-Bar-Buttons-using-jQuery.aspx

```
// Simple Method to Add a Custom Button to the NavBar using jQuery
var addNavButton = function (mapElement, content, onclick) {
    $(mapElement).find('.NavBar_typeButtonContainer').append(
        // Add a Separator between this button and any existing buttons
        $('<span>').addClass('NavBar_separator')
    ).append(
        // Add the Custom Button itself
        $('<a>').attr('href', '#').addClass('NavBar_button').
            append($('<span>').html(content).click(onclick))
    );
};
// Use setTimeout to load Custom NavBar button if you are adding
// the button immediatly after instantiating the map.
// Timeout is needed since Bing Maps 7 doesn't currently have
// any kind of "onload" event to handle.
window.setTimeout(function () {
    // Add Custom Button to NavBar
    addNavButton(
        document.getElementById('myMap'), // <- Maps DIV
        'Click Me', // <- Content of Button - You can put HTML in here if you want
        function () { // <- Method to call during buttons Click event
            alert('You Clicked Me!');
        }
    );
}, 100);
```